# Restart Varnish on each instance of AWS Opsworks

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, caching, varnish, aws-opsworks

I have a WordPress site in AWS Opsworks with some self-scaling policies. So, sometimes I'll had more than one instance of WordPress.

I need to run a Varnish purge for some specific urls when I save a post but I don't know how can I do this on each instance. As I have configured the stack each instance has its own varnish service and I need to purge on each instance in order to see changes immediately.

Comment: Why do you need a varnish restart on a post save? If you set the cache headers properly you can, and should, just flush a specific cache entry so that the backend will start consuming it?

Comment: @Dirkos you are right, I edited my question. I need to flush a specific cache entry on each instance.